How do i make PWM be in the middle of the other one
Sorry if I worded my question wrong, I don't know how I should describe it.
I'm making an inverter circuit for my class project.
This is my MOSFET driver circuit:

This is the output:

The 2nd PWM signal is rising at the same time as the 1st PWM is falling.
Here's my question:
How do I get it so that the 2nd PWM rise and fall while the 1st PWM is off like in this image:  From this website

I like custard - Hi, Where did the image with dead time come from? To comply with the site rule on referencing, details of the original source of copied / adapted material must be provided by you, next to each copied / adapted item. If the original source is online (webpage, PDF, video etc.) please [edit] the question & add its name & link (URL) (e.g. website name + webpage title + its URL). Always reference to the best of your ability. TY (Please see the [tour] & [help] for the main site rules - they differ from typical forums.)


How do I get it so that the 2nd PWM rise and fall while the 1st PWM is
off like in this image

Very much more simply by using a single channel of PWM and an anti-shoot-through circuit like this: -

Image taken from here. Note that the longer the RC time constant, the bigger the gap between the two outputs being high.
